# Main method exists. Even then: Static Error: This class does not have a static void main method accepting String[]

Tags: java, static, program-entry-point, drjava

the main method exists in ques4 class, the file is named as ques4.java . but every time I run the code, the same error comes up.

This is the question: Write a function that takes time as three integer arguments (hours, minutes, seconds) and returns the number of seconds since the clock last struck 12.

```
import java.util.*;
class time
{
      int time(int h, int m, int s)
    {
        if(h>12)
        {
            int r = ((h-12)*3600) + (m*60) + s;
            return r;
        }
        else 
        {
            int r = (h*3600) + (m*60) + s;
            return r;
        }
    }
}

class ques4
{
    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        time ob = new time();
    Scanner ob1 = new Scanner (System.in);
    int hr, mi, se;
    System.out.println("Enter time in 12 hour format. First enter Hours then 
minutes and then seconds");
    hr=ob1.nextInt();
    mi=ob1.nextInt();
    se=ob1.nextInt();
    ob.time(hr,mi,se);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your class must be public. `public class ques4`

Comment: @Jens Just did. it worked. thanks!

Comment: You are welcome